# Solving a PDE with a squared partial derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Here's the PDE that needs to be solved analytically for $p(x,t)$:

$$\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} \right)^2+(p+p_0)\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} = 0,$$

where $p_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, subject to

$$p(0,t)=e^{-t}, \: p(L,t)=0.$$

The thing that is throwing me off is the $(\partial p/\partial x)^2$ term, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be reduced to a Bernoulli ODE of order 2.

Comment: Note that that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(p\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})=(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})^2+p\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate once quite easily: note that
$$ \partial_x ((p-p_0)\partial_x p) = (\partial_x p)^2 + (p-p_0)\partial_x^2 p $$
(where $\partial_x = \partial/\partial x$) by the product rule. Hence we can integrate once immediately:
$$ (p-p_0)\partial_x p = A(t). $$
We can integrate again by noticing that $\partial_x(p-p_0)^2 = 2(p-p_0)\partial_x p$ by the chain rule. So
$$ \frac{1}{2}(p-p_0)^2 = A(t)x + B(t). $$
Putting $x=0$ and $x=L$,
$$ B(t) = \frac{1}{2}(p(0,t)-p_0)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t}-p_0)^2 \\
A(t)L + B(t) = \frac{1}{2}(p(L,t)-p_0)^2 = \frac{1}{2}p_0^2, $$
and then solve these two equations simultaneously to find $B(t)$ and $A(t)$.